# Non blocking flow with Mulesoft

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I have a mule flow that has to work the following way.

- HTTP listener listens to incoming calls and immediately responds with a job id.
- The incoming message is queued into a worker. It works on it for a while and returns the message back to the sender.

I tried using non-blocking flow. But it didn't work. How is such a thing architected in Mulesoft? Would be great to have any leads on this.

Comment: "It works on it for a while and returns the message back to the sender." - How do you intend to send a message back? As a response of the same HTTP request? Or Caller has a callback URL/mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could use an [async](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/async-scope-reference) scope for that second part. This would allow the HTTP listener to trigger that part and yet respond immediately with a response.

Answer (score 0):

flow one   Http listner---->Async Vm queue ---->set  Jon ID--->Send response

Flow two   VM inbound--->Process message-->Http requestor